# Can we get a torus by identifying surface with removed disc and mobius strip?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

If we take a surface and remove a disc, then identify this resulting circle with the boundary circle.. does this produce a torus?

Comment: Nope. Once you glue in a Möbius strip your surface becomes non-orientable, so can't be a torus.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip:  That should probably be an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Once you glue in a Möbius strip your surface becomes non-orientable, so can't be a torus.